# Применить Comparer при выполнении LINQ JOIN

Tags: c#, linq

Можно ли как-нибудь применить особый Comparer при соединении 2-ух последовательностей синтаксисом запросов?

Например, есть 2 листа и я хочу их без учета регистра соединить.

Конечно я могу между `equals` все привести в верхний регистр, но это не совсем верно.

Можно ли как-то задать метод сравнения явно?

```
static List<(string, string)> GetDifferent(IEnumerable<string> list1, IEnumerable<string> list2)
{
    var left = from item1 in list1
               join item2 in list2 on item1.ToUpper() equals item2.ToUpper()
                   into temp
               from item2 in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select (item1, item2);

    var right = from item2 in list2
                join item1 in list1 on item2.ToUpper() equals item1.ToUpper()
                    into temp
                from item1 in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select (item1, item2);
    return left.Union(right).Where(x => x.Item1 == null || x.Item2 == null).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Покажите пример запроса

Comment: @АндрейNOP, приложил.

Comment: Скорее всего только во Fluent-синтаксисе можно

Comment: Нет, в `join` можно указать только точное соответствие: `equals`. Но можно вместо него использовать `where` и там уже заюзать компаратор.

Comment: Под Fluent вы понимаете синтаксис методов?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, можно пример в виде ответа, как это все будет выглядеть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В *query-syntax* для [`join`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause) доступен лишь [оператор равенства `equals`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause#the-equals-operator).

Однако, метод [`Join`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Join__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1___2__System_Func___0___1___3__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___2__) имеет перегрузку принимающую *IEqualityComparer*.

Так как в коде left outer join, то следует использовать метод [`GroupJoin`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupJoin__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1___2__System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1____3__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___2__), который также имеет перегрузку принимающую *IEqualityComparer*.

Например:

```
IEqualityComparer ec = ...;
var left = list1.GroupJoin(
    list2,
    item1 => item1,
    item2 => item2,
    (item1, items2) => new {item1, items2}
    ec
).SelectMany(
    item => item.items2.DefaultIfEmpty(),
    (item, item2) => (item.item1, item2)
);
```

Comment: Т.е в синтаксисе запросов вообще никак кастомно сравнить элементы?

Comment: @iluxa1810, да. С другой стороны. можно реализовать `IComparer` какой-нибудь, и попробовать за счет него, но тогда нужно будет менять сам класс

Comment: @iluxa1810, либо сделать обертку принимающую компаратор и объект, и который бы как раз переопределял свой `==`

Answer (score 2):

В синтаксисе запросов linq в `join` можно указать только точное соответствие: `equals`. Но можно вместо него использовать `where` и там уже использовать компаратор.

Аналогом этого кода:

```
from item1 in list1
join item2 in list2
on item1.ToUpper() equals item2.ToUpper()
select (item1, item2);
```

будет следующий:

```
from item1 in list1
from item2 in list2
where item1.Equals(item2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
select (item1, item2);
```

Но я затрудняюсь преобразовать в эту форму код с использованием `into`.

---

Для исключения элементов одной последовательности из другой можно (нужно) применять метод `Except`:

```
list1.Except(list2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

list2.Except(list1, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Соответственно, полный код может выглядеть как-то так:

```
var left = list1.Except(list2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    .Select(item => (item, (string)null));

var right = list2.Except(list1, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    .Select(item => ((string)null, item));

return left.Union(right).ToList();
```